# pandas between statement for two dates from another dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

What formula can I use to determine based off of a certain date the pay period number that falls between a start date and end date?  In other words, from df1 I have a date that I need to compare against df2 start dates and end dates and then produce the pay period that those dates fall within in a new data set.

The formula I've used so far is the following.  Keep in mind I'm not a seasoned programmer:

1st try:

```
def calc(row):
    if pf2(row['actn_dt']) >= pp_calendar([0], and pf2(row['actn_dt']) <= df2([1]):
        return df2([2,3])
```

2nd try:

```
pf2['pay'] = np.where (pf2['actn_dt'] >= df2[0]) | (pf2['actn_dt'] <= pf2[1]), pp_calendar[2]
```

3rd try:

```
def calc(row):
    if pf2(row['actn_dt']) >= df2(row[1]) | pf2(row['actn_dt']) <= df2(row[2]):
        return df2(row[3])


pf2['pay'] = pf2.apply (lambda row: calc(row), axis=1)
```

print df:

```
                actn_dt
16   2008-09-28 00:00:00
17   2008-03-16 00:00:00
18   2009-08-30 00:00:00
43   2008-06-22 00:00:00
89   2009-08-16 00:00:00
106  2009-03-29 00:00:00
244  2009-08-30 00:00:00
371  2009-09-13 00:00:00
400  2009-07-19 00:00:00
439  2007-12-23 00:00:00
```

print df2:

```
        START_DATE   END_DATE           PAY_PERIOD   CALENDAR_YEAR
0       2008-09-28   2008-10-11         10           2008
1       2008-03-16   2008-03-16         06           2008
2       2009-08-30   2009-09-12         18           2009
3       2008-06-22   2008-06-22         13           2008
4       2009-03-29   2009-04-11         07           2009
```

Expected Result:

```
     actn_dt      START_DATE    END_DATE     PAY_PERIOD   CALENDAR_YEAR
16   2008-09-28   2008-09-28    2008-10-11   10           2008
17   2008-03-16   2008-03-16    2008-03-29   06           2008   
18   2009-08-30   2009-08-30    2009-09-12   18           2009
43   2008-06-22   2008-06-22    2008-07-05   13           2008
89   2009-08-16   2009-08-16    2008-08-29   17           2009
106  2009-03-29   2009-03-29    2009-04-11   07           2009
244  2009-08-30   2009-08-30    2009-09-12   18           2009
```

Thank you for your knowledge and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Head Line Solution

```
def find_pay_period(date, df):
    df = df[(df.START_DATE <= date) & (date <= df.END_DATE)].iloc[0, :]
    df['actn_dt'] = date
    return df

df1.actn_dt.apply(lambda x: find_pay_period(x, df2))
```

#### Explanation

start with

```
# apply() will take date in df1 and find the first row in df2
# such that the date is between START_DATE and END_DATE and
# then return the row.
df1.actn_dt.apply(lambda x: find_pay_period(x, df2))
```

now this

```
def find_pay_period(date, df):
    # df[] use boolean mask to filter
    # .iloc[0, :] grabs first row of filtered DataFrame.
    # Keep in mind this is a Series.
    df = df[(df.START_DATE <= date) & (date <= df.END_DATE)].iloc[0, :]
    # add back your date
    df['actn_dt'] = date
    return df
```

Comment: Works perfectly!  You're explanation was extremely valuable with me understanding how it all fit together too.